# How to trigger the pushEvent of Push API in order to show the notification(s)?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to make a push notification web program that the user can subscribe it. I hope the notifications show even if the user closed the page or even the whole window, like Facebook's notification system. Below is the excerpt code I found from [serviceworke.rs](https://serviceworke.rs/push-subscription-management.html):

index.js:

```
function getSubscription() {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(function(registration) {
      return registration.pushManager.getSubscription();
    });
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
    .then(function() {
      console.log('service worker registered');
    });

  getSubscription()
    .then(function(subscription) {
      if (subscription) {
        console.log('Already subscribed', subscription.endpoint);
      }
    });
}

function subscribe() {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
    return registration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true });
  }).then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('Subscribed', subscription.endpoint);
    return fetch('register', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        endpoint: subscription.endpoint
      })
    });
  });
}

function unsubscribe() {
  getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
    return subscription.unsubscribe()
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Unsubscribed', subscription.endpoint);
        return fetch('unregister', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            endpoint: subscription.endpoint
          })
        });
      });
  });
}
```

service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification('ServiceWorker Cookbook', {
    body: 'Push Notification Subscription Management'
  }));
});

self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', function(event) {
  console.log('Subscription expired');
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true })
    .then(function(subscription) {
      console.log('Subscribed after expiration', subscription.endpoint);
      return fetch('register', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          endpoint: subscription.endpoint
        })
      });
    })
  );
});
```

The question is: how do the server trigger the `push` event in `service-worker.js`? And how do the notification work even if the tab or even the whole window is closed?

Another problem is when I put this recipe (Push Subscription recipe) onto my server and ran it, the browser told me the URL 'register' and 'unregister' were not found, which are the first parameters of both fetch APIs. How should I solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

*P.S. I use PHP as my server-side language.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WebPush library on your server to send the notifications. There is a PHP version here:

https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

I have not used the PHP version, but the nodejs version was very straightforward to set up.

Next, (on Chrome browser at least) your notifications will stack up when the browser is closed, and they will all appear when the browser is next opened.

Finally, you cannot reach your API from the browser because your browser is sending GET requests, and your server is waiting for POST requests.